# How to get calling method name in win 10 universal app

Tags: win-universal-app

I am migrating my application from Windows phone 8.1 to Win10 universal app.
At one point I need the name of the calling method. Formerly i did this using:

```
new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name
```

But this API is no longer supportet as I found out in https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1420

For some logging reasons I need the name of the calling method. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this implementation will require that you define optional parameters in the method where you expect to access the name of the calling method. Hence if you need it only in specific places (for example: a method that will log an exception), then you can use the `CallerMemberName`attribute found in the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace.

You can see an example in the [CallerMemberNameAttribute class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx)

Comment: Works fine! Thank you